# How to configure and run Solr full dataimport from MySQL using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, solr

I need to perform full import or delta import programmatically using python and mysql. I am aware of the process in java. We can do it in following way:

```
CommonsHttpSolrServer server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("command", "full-import");
QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
request.setPath("/dataimport");
server.request(request);
```

I am trying to implement it in python. Can you suggest the equivalent code in python or any solr python api that supports this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few python APIs, but I use mysolr (http://mysolr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/userguide.html) because you can use json in indexing, making it faster.

```
    from mysolr import Solr

    ## For full index, delete all data after final commit:
    solr.delete_by_query('*:*', commit=False)

    solr = Solr("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection", version=4)
    documents = [
        {'id' : 1,
         'field1' : 'foo'
        },
        {'id' : 2,
         'field1' : 'bar'
        }
    ]

    solr.update(documents, 'json', commit=False)
    solr.commit()
```

You can query like 1000 records at a time, create a list of them ("documents" above), and send them to the solr index. Then when finished, do the commit. If it's a full query, you can clear all data without committing, and the old data will be deleted once you do the final commit.

Comment: Does it support solr 6.3? I am trying to implement  it but it is not working

Comment: Could you be more specific on what is not working? Use the python shell to do the test, and write out the error message. I use solr 5.1, but I've also tested it on solr 6.3. The version=4 above refers to solr 4, because there were changes in the solr API between versions 3 and 4 (the only options are 1, 3, and 4). The "collection" in the URL should be the name of your collection.

Answer (score 1):

You trigger the DataImportHandler by making a single HTTP request, and the Java example is just a way to do that using the SolrJ package.

In native python3 you can do this by using `urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/dataimport?command=full-import')
```

In python2 the same function is available under `urllib2`:

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/dataimport?command=full-import')
```

Or if you're using the `requests` library (which can be installed through `pip install requests`):

```
import requests
requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/dataimport?command=full-import')
```

Comment: I am aware of these methods. I just wanted to know is there any python api similar to solrJ for solr 6.3. I stated working with sunburnt but it doesn't work at all for version grtr than solr 4.8. Can you suggest some alternatives??